# SSL ProtocolException on Java 11

Tags: java, spring-boot, ssl-certificate, tls1.2

I have recently migrated my springboot application from Springboot 1, Java 8 to Spring boot 2, Java 11. This was working fine on 8 so far.
This springboot application is a cron job which runs daily and processes thousands of records.
For each record this application calls another app to retrieve some response (both apps are running on Java 11).

The strange thing is I am getting this exception only while processing few records (say about 100s) rest works fine.

Below is the exception stacktrace:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLProtocolException: Connection reset
         at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:126)
         at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:321)
         at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:264)
         at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:259)
         at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.handleException(SSLSocketImpl.java:1314)
         at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl$AppInputStream.read(SSLSocketImpl.java:839)
         at org.apache.http.impl.io.SessionInputBufferImpl.streamRead(SessionInputBufferImpl.java:137)
         at org.apache.http.impl.io.SessionInputBufferImpl.fillBuffer(SessionInputBufferImpl.java:153)
         at org.apache.http.impl.io.SessionInputBufferImpl.readLine(SessionInputBufferImpl.java:280)
         at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:140)
         at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:57)
         at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractMessageParser.parse(AbstractMessageParser.java:259)
         at org.apache.http.impl.DefaultBHttpClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(DefaultBHttpClientConnection.java:163)
         at org.apache.http.impl.conn.CPoolProxy.receiveResponseHeader(CPoolProxy.java:153)
         at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.doReceiveResponse(HttpRequestExecutor.java:273)
         at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.execute(HttpRequestExecutor.java:125)
         at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:254)
         at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:195)
         at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:86)
         at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:108)
         at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:184)
         at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:82)
         at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:106)
         at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:57)
         at com.win.billpayalerts.service.EcmService.getEcmInfoWithRetryCount(EcmService.java:171)
         at com.win.billpayalerts.service.EcmService.getEcmAccountInfoByEcmContactId(EcmService.java:91)
         at com.win.billpayalerts.service.EcmService.getEcmAccountInfoByEcmContactId(EcmService.java:362)
         at com.win.billpayalerts.service.AlertService.getEcmInfoForCustomer(AlertService.java:233)
         at com.win.billpayalerts.service.InvoiceAlertProcessor.processInvoice(InvoiceAlertProcessor.java:48)
         at com.win.billpayalerts.service.AlertProcessor.invokeNotificationAlert(AlertProcessor.java:70)
         at com.win.billpayalerts.service.AlertProcessor.run(AlertProcessor.java:44)
         at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:779)
         at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunners(SpringApplication.java:763)
         at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:318)
         at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1213)
         at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1202)
         at com.win.billpayalerts.BillpayAlertsApplication.main(BillpayAlertsApplication.java:10)
         at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
         at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
         at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
         at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
         at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:47)
         at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:86)
         at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:50)
         at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:51)
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
         at java.base/java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:186)
         at java.base/java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:140)
         at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.read(SSLSocketInputRecord.java:448)
         at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.bytesInCompletePacket(SSLSocketInputRecord.java:68)
         at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readApplicationRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1104)
         at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl$AppInputStream.read(SSLSocketImpl.java:823)
         ... 39 common frames omitted
```

This is the gradle file of the source application:

```
plugins {
  id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.1.6.RELEASE'
  id 'java'
}

apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: 'jacoco'
apply plugin: 'checkstyle'
apply plugin: 'jdepend'

sourceCompatibility = 1.11
targetCompatibility = 1.11


bootJar {
  archiveBaseName = 'alerts'
}


repositories {
  mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
  compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa')
  compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jdbc') {
    exclude group: 'org.apache.tomcat', module: 'tomcat-jdbc'
  }
  compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
  compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-mail')

  compile("org.apache.axis:axis:1.4")
  compile('org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.5')
  compile('org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.3.4')
  compile('org.apache.pdfbox:pdfbox:2.0.1')

  compile("net.sf.ehcache:ehcache:2.10.3")

  compile("commons-discovery:commons-discovery:0.5")
  compile("com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-xml:2.8.4")

  compile('ch.qos.logback:logback-core:1.1.8')
  compile('ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.1.8')
  compile("wsdl4j:wsdl4j:1.6.2")


  runtime('com.microsoft:sqljdbc4:4.0')

  testRuntime('com.h2database:h2')
  testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
  testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.4'
}
```

This is the gradle file of the another application:

```
 plugins {
   id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.1.6.RELEASE'
   id 'java'
 }

 apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'
 apply plugin: 'java'
 apply plugin: 'eclipse'
 apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
 apply plugin: 'jacoco'
 apply plugin: 'checkstyle'
 apply plugin: 'jdepend'

 sourceCompatibility = 1.11

 bootJar {
   baseName = 'accounts'
 } 


 repositories {
   mavenCentral()
 }

 dependencies {
   implementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter')
   compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator')
   compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-cache')
   compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
   compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-mail')
   compile("io.springfox:springfox-swagger2:2.7.0")
   compile("io.springfox:springfox-swagger-ui:2.7.0")

   compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jdbc') {
      exclude group: 'org.apache.tomcat', module: 'tomcat-jdbc'
   }

   compile('org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.5')
   compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa')
   compile('org.apache.commons:commons-collections4:4.0')
   compile group: 'net.sf.jt400', name: 'jt400-jdk8', version: '9.5'
   compile('org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.3.4')
   compile('log4j:log4j:1.2.17')
   compile('org.projectlombok:lombok')
   runtime('com.microsoft:sqljdbc4:4.0')

   testCompile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-test'
   testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit'
 }
```

I tried by disabling TLSv1.3 via the JVM argument but that did not work:

```
-Djdk.tls.client.protocols="TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2"
```

How do I resolve this issue? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Most likely the server didn't like your client certificate.

Comment: Is your new java 11 setup running on the same server as your old?

Comment: @Scratte: No, its on different server

Comment: @user207421: A agree that to some extent but I'm getting this exception while processing only few records in between rest works fine

Answer (score 3):

Not really an answer, more a suspicion, and too long for a comment:

Since you're getting `Connection reset`, and not `Connection reset by peer`, I suspect the reset is done by the java application itself or the server it's running on. I looked at the source code for `SocketInputStream.read`. It's reading based on a timeout value:

```
try {
    n = socketRead(fd, b, off, length, timeout);
    if (n > 0) {
        return n;
    }
} catch (ConnectionResetException rstExc) {
    impl.setConnectionReset();
} finally {
    impl.releaseFD();
}
```

My **guess** is that the `ConnectionResetException` is thrown due to a reset from the server, that also sets the value of the timeout (on the connection, not the read).

I don't know if you have logs of the records with success along with those that failed, but if you do, maybe you can check timestamps to see if my suspicions are heading the right way.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, I see ~4 seconds response time for the calls which threw Connection reset exceptions rest of the successive records took just ~1 sec. I'm not seeing any 504 error though.

Comment: If you can run your Java 8 version of the application on the same server and you get the same error, then it must be a configuration issue on the server. If you can't do that, maybe check the configurations of the protocols on both servers.

Comment: I will try that too, thanks for your time, appreciated.